# Can't deploy firebase cloud function for flutter

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\Android Projects\buy_storage_try\buy\functions\index.js:21:45)
```

And this is the line of code:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')(gcconfig);
```

full error message:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\Android Projects\buy_storage_try\buy\functions\index.js:21:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at C:\Users\itzpa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\itzpa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:53:3)
```

The code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fbAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const gcconfig = {
  projectId: '***',
  keyFilename: '***.json'
};

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')(gcconfig);

fbAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: fbAdmin.credential.cert(require('./***.json'))
});

exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Not allowed.' });
    }

    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')
    ) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized.' });
    }

    let idToken;
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let uploadData;
    let oldImagePath;

    busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
      uploadData = { filePath: filePath, type: mimetype, name: filename };
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
    });

    busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
      oldImagePath = decodeURIComponent(value);
    });

    busboy.on('finish', () => {
      const bucket = gcs.bucket('flutter-buy.appspot.com');
      const id = uuid();
      let imagePath = 'images/' + id + '-' + uploadData.name;
      if (oldImagePath) {
        imagePath = oldImagePath;
      }

      return fbAdmin
        .auth()
        .verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(decodedToken => {
          return bucket.upload(uploadData.filePath, {
            uploadType: 'media',
            destination: imagePath,
            metadata: {
              metadata: {
                contentType: uploadData.type,
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: id
              }
            }
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          return res.status(201).json({
            imageUrl:
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/' +
              bucket.name +
              '/o/' +
              encodeURIComponent(imagePath) +
              '?alt=media&token=' +
              id,
            imagePath: imagePath
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized!' });
        });
    });
    return busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  });
});
```

Comment: What version of @google/cloud-storage are you using, and what documentation are you using that suggests your code should be correct?

Comment: @google-cloud/storage@2.3.1
I'm using a video tutorial by Maximilian Schwarzmüller

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of `gcconfig`.
Should work just fine.

```
const projectId = 'your-project-id';
const keyFilename = 'your-keyfile.json';

const {
    Storage
} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const gcs = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: keyFilename
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of @google-cloud/storage greater then or equal to 2.0.0.  The APIs changed in 2.0.0.  The tutorial you're following is out of date and was probably written against 1.x.

Look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage#using-the-client-library) for the module.  The way to initialize the SDK is like this:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. was very helpful. Your solution is simple and easy to follow